# Which DNS should I use?

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, centos

I have a CentOS virtual server and I registered a domain and set its ns1 and ns2 name servers. I plan to run one site on my VPS. I know that BIND is a common DNS. But I think using it is overkill. Which DNS is best for this situation?

Answer (score 3):

Unless you have a specific reason to want to run your own DNS servers then you should use the one provided by your registrar.

Comment: He could run dnsmasq if he was looking for a local cache.

Comment: If I do not set up a dns on my VPS, how can I use my domain that I registered by another company? currently I can access my web site using ip of VPS.

Comment: @RezaS: You create an A record in your DNS pointing the domainname to the IP address of your VPS.